# JavaScript function wait until Callback return value

Tags: javascript, callback

Is there any way I can make my js function wait until the callback return value. I need this because the rest part of my js function have to use the returned value from the callback.

Comment: you may set interval and check a variable.. but that's not the good thing to do.

Comment: Can you show some code explaining what you want to do ?

Comment: Are you using an ajax call or something?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of libraries or frameworks offer comfort callback value. Yoy can look for the [Jquery promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/,), [bluebird promise](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html), [angular promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

If you do not want to use third party libs, you can implement them by yourself, using setInterval method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make your function to wait until the callback return. What you can do is move the rest of your workflow to the success call back of the function.

I have put a sample code of Ajax call here.

```
    $.get( _RequestURL, function () {}).done(function (success) {
        //Put the rest of your workflow here.

    }).fail(function (err) {
        //Put the error handler methods here.

    });
```